Copy Data from cell to another cell in the same table
I have this:
ID   |   NAME    |  VALUE  |
----------------------------
 1   |   Test1   |  VALUE1 |
 2   |   Test2   |         |
 3   |   Test3   |         |
 4   |   Test4   |         |
 5   |   Test5   |         |

I want to copy VALUE1 over to row Test 5 VALUE column.  Desired end result:
ID   |   NAME    |  VALUE  |
----------------------------
 1   |   Test1   |  VALUE1 |
 2   |   Test2   |         |
 3   |   Test3   |         |
 4   |   Test4   |         |
 5   |   Test5   |  VALUE1 |

This is driving me crazy, it can't be that hard.

With apologies for pedantry, but databases are not spreadsheets. MySQL, and RDBMs in general, do not have "cells".

Why have the IDs changed in the desired result?

You can ignore the ID's.  They are of no help in this scenario.

You could use a subquery to obtain the Test1 column:
UPDATE yourTable
SET VALUE = (SELECT VALUE FROM yourTable WHERE NAME = 'Test1')
WHERE NAME = 'Test5';

Note that the above will fail if there be more than one record having the name Test1.  A safer update here would instead use the unique ID column:
UPDATE yourTable
SET VALUE = (SELECT VALUE FROM yourTable WHERE ID = 1)
WHERE ID = 5;


This seems close, however I am getting "Subquery returns more than 1 row".

The ID column can be ignored...pretend it isn't there.
